# getting sql error:hour must be between 1 and 12

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a problem with a query I use to report.I get an error comparing a value stored as a timestamp with data saved yesterday.

query:

```
SELECT * FROM PIECE P, PIECE_ATTRB PA WHERE P.PIECE_NUM_ID=PA.PIECE_NUM_ID
AND PA.ATTRB_CODE='PRODUCTION_CUT_DATE'
AND PA.ATTRB_AN_VALUE  >=cast(TRUNC(SYSDATE-1)+ INTERVAL '00:00:00'  HOUR TO SECOND AS timestamp)
AND pa.ATTRB_AN_VALUE < CAST(TRUNC(SYSDATE)+ INTERVAL '00:00:00'  HOUR TO SECOND AS timestamp)
```

Sample value for pa.attrb_an_value : 03-FEB-21 23:43:26,000000

But I get the following error.

> hour must be between 1 and 12

Comment: What is the datatype of the column attrb_an_value ?

Comment: `INTERVAL '00:00:00'  HOUR TO SECOND` is pointless, just skip it.

Comment: I use it for string value so  Varchar2.

Comment: **Never** store date/time values as string,  it's a design flaw. Use `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data type.

Comment: I skip it , but I have to keep it as a varchar2 because this is a table that affects many things @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: Date-like strings formatted in `'dd-MON-yyyy'` cannot be sorted (beginnings of all the month will be the at the first place). You should use at least `'yyyymmddhh24miss'` for string value or `date` datatype for all the features of filtering

Comment: So what we have here is the Entity-Attribute-Value so-called model. This is SQL Anti-pattern of the first order. It scales badly, it contributes to data corruption and, as you're discovering, is terrible to query. None of which helps you solve your problem right now, sorry about that. I suggest you query **all** the values of PA.ATTRB_AN_VALUE for PA.ATTRB_CODE='PRODUCTION_CUT_DATE'. I bet you've got at least one which doesn't match the format you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

you can first convert the date into timestamp. Instead of ATTRB_AN_VALUE  please use

```
to_timestamp(substr(ATTRB_AN_VALUE,1,18),'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SSFF3')
```

This will convert the value into **03-FEB-21 11.43.26.000000 PM** and it will eliminate the error.

Comment: This answer really worked,After converting the value as you say the error is eliminated.
Thanks for focusing on the issue and helping.

Answer (score 0):

Since the column attrb_an_value is not a DATE or TIMESTAMP but a VARCHAR2, you cannot compare it to a date without some casting. The `TO_TIMESTAMP` function will take a string and convert that to a timestamp value with a given format mask.

```
SELECT
  *
  FROM
  piece        p,
  piece_attrb  pa
 WHERE
      p.piece_num_id = pa.piece_num_id AND
  pa.attrb_code = 'PRODUCTION_CUT_DATE' AND
  TO_TIMESTAMP(pa.attrb_an_value,'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS,FF6') >=  TRUNC(systimestamp,'DD') - INTERVAL '1' DAY AND
  TO_TIMESTAMP(pa.attrb_an_value,'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS,FF6') <  TRUNC(systimestamp,'DD')
```

Note 1: This will fail as soon as a row does not contain a string matching the `DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS,FF6` format mask.

Note 2: As others pointed out, this is a serious design flaw. No date or timestamp data should be stored in VARCHAR2 columns.

Comment: Looks like it's a EAV anti-model. Probably all their data is stored as a string.

Comment: I am aware of this, but this table is designed for a different function, I need to take this value as a string.

Comment: It will be interesting how will it handle different country preferences. Apart from bad design you can add  calculated column with `to_timestamp` applied to values of desired type to save the time for future people who will want to query this table. This will not corrupt your data and can also be indexed for date lookups. @Hakanözel

Comment: Different programming languages ​​such as sap, c # provide access to this table and I only have the authorization to edit on oracle.

Comment: Nothing to do about it then. I was just pointing out that this is not a good practice. Please mark the question as answered if you're satisfied with my reply

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is about formatting the date. Here's the correct formatting. Also, I thought that you wanted result set that contained PA's ATTRB_AN_VALUE values in between the beginning of yesterday and today. So, the answer contains the simplified version of compared dates.

```
SELECT * FROM PIECE P, PIECE_ATTRB PA WHERE P.PIECE_NUM_ID=PA.PIECE_NUM_ID
AND PA.ATTRB_CODE='PRODUCTION_CUT_DATE'
AND to_timestamp(PA.ATTRB_AN_VALUE,'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS,FF')  >=to_timestamp(trunc(sysdate-1))
AND to_timestamp(pa.ATTRB_AN_VALUE,'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS,FF') < to_timestamp(trunc(sysdate));
```

Comment: Thank you @APC for warning me. I edited my answer.